# Multiple Data Types in JSON

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, geometry

I am accessing a API that has geometries object types in an JSON Object. The issue I have is in my Kotlin model class (below), I cannot have two Object Types for the node, as I get hit with the error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a double but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 12 column 16 path $.features[0].geometry.geometries[0].coordinates[0];`

because for the each inner node ***coordinates*** ofeach object, it can either return:

```
List<Double> 
List<List<Double>>
```

**API JSON**

```
"geometries": [
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [153.0533903,-26.7735391]
      },
      {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [153.0258962, -27.3399828],
          [153.02596, -27.34007],
          [153.02602, -27.34015],
          [153.026028, -27.3401745]
        ]
      }
 ]
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

The external API response is passed through Retrofit models, however in my model class how do provide both `List<Double>` & `List<List<Double>>` processing

```
public class EventsGeometriesAPINodeModel {

   @SerializedName("type")
   @Expose
   internal var type: String? = null

   //how do provide both List<Double> List<List<Double>> processing
   //API retruns either:
   //List<Double> 
   //List<List<Double>>

   @SerializedName("coordinates")
   @Expose
   internal var coordinates: List<Double>? = null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make coordinates variable dynamic like JsonArray and whenever you receive data then you have to check type of that variable.

```
val listCoordinates = jsonObject.coordinates
if(listCoordinates is List<Double>){

} else if(listCoordinates is List<List<Double>>){

}
```

Comment: The external API response is passed through Retrofit models so not sure I can access the JSON before it hits further processing in the models

Comment: You have to just change List<Double> to JsonArray in model. After you can check type when data is received.

Comment: Thanks @Dhrumil changing List<Double> to JsonArray in model seemed to work well and now able to do coordinates.ForEach{} processing